# ScrollTo covers a greater distance on each click

Tags: jquery, slider, scrollto, jquery-ui-slider

Hi I was hoping someone could help.

I'm using the ScrollTo jquery plugin and on each click to scroll towards the left it incrementally covers a greater distance. Conversely clicking to scroll towards the right sending the items back the other way incrementally covers a lesser distance.

You can see the example [here](http://psd2htmlservice.com/scrolltest/index2.html)

I was wondering if people could view the source to have a better look at what's going on but the actual code I'm using to invoke the function is this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#streetstyles_right_arrow").click(function() {
        $("#streetstyles-pane").scrollTo({top:'+=0px',left:'+=470px'}, 370);
        $("#streetstyles-pane2").scrollTo({top:'+=0px',left:'+=470px'}, 370);
    });

    $("#streetstyles_left_arrow").click(function(){
        $("#streetstyles-pane").scrollTo({top:'+=0px',left:'-=470px'}, 370);
        $("#streetstyles-pane2").scrollTo({top:'+=0px',left:'-=470px'}, 370);
    });         
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

jQuery ScrollTo covers a greater distance on each click.

Answer (score 0):

You're scrolling too far. If you want to scroll `470px`, then the width of the boxes should be `460px` (+ `5px` right padding, + `5px` right margin). Their current width is `450px`.

Alternatively, reduce the width to scroll by 10px.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `document.ready` code to this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#streetstyles_right_arrow").click(function(){
        $("#streetstyles-pane").scrollTo({top:'+=0px',left:'+=460px'}, 370);
        $("#streetstyles-pane2").scrollTo({top:'+=0px',left:'+=480px'}, 370);
    });

    $("#streetstyles_left_arrow").click(function(){
        $("#streetstyles-pane").scrollTo({top:'+=0px',left:'-=460px'}, 370);
        $("#streetstyles-pane2").scrollTo({top:'+=0px',left:'-=480px'}, 370);
    });
});
```

The first pane was scrolling too far and the 2nd pane wasn't scrolling far enough.